# can paging be slower/faster than swapping on a machine?

Tags: memory, operating-system

This is a very naive question, but I wonder if there is any comparison that can be made on paging or swapping speed? They are offering the same functionality (moving from memory to disk, etc) but with different strategies (writing frames, or writing down the whole memory). Now the problem is, can one of them be faster than the other? And what does this depend on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paging always happens. It's just a mechanism of mapping virtual memory. Swapping is "paging + disk I/O", so therefore no, paging is neither an alternative to swapping nor can be slower than swapping itself.